# "Permission Denied" error in IE when it enters failure block, ExtJS

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, extjs

1. I have used filefield xtype to upload a file and calling a web service.
2. For my application, to handle success and failure block, i am using a variable 'success' such that if the value is true, it goes to success block and if the value is false, it goes to failure block.
3. If i set the value success=false, it comes to failure block but, when i decode the response it gives me "permission denied" error only in IE. In Chrome, we get the expected output even if it enters the failure block.
4. Since i am getting this error, i am handling this failure case in success block itself.

Below is the code snippet:

```js
form.submit({
 headers : {
  "Accept" : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
 },
 url : 'calling a web service',
 waitMsg : 'Loading... Please Wait...',
 success : function (response, args) {
  var jsonResp = Ext.decode(args.response.responseText);
  if (jsonResp.exception) {
   Ext.create('widget.uxNotification', {
    title : 'Failed',
    height : 150,
    width : 350,
    html : '<span style="text-align:center; display:block;color:red">' + jsonResp.R.MSG + '</span>'
   }).show();
  } else {
   //actual code if success=true goes here
  }
 },
 failure : function (response, args) {
  var jsonResp = Ext.decode(args.response.responseText); //if i decode the response, i get permission denied
  var msg = jsonResp.R.MSG || jsonResp.R.Message; 
                //R.MSG is undefined even if it is present in response and R.Message gives permission denied
  Ext.Msg.alert(msg);
 }
});
```

json Response for success case:

```js
{  
   "success":true,
   "R":{  
      "MSG":"Success"
   }
}
```

json Response for failure case:

```js
{  
   "success":true,
   "exception":true,
   "R":{  
      "MSG":"Failure"
   }
}
```

5. I am sending another parameter 'exception' in the response to handle this. So if exception is true then it's actually a failure case.

Is it a bug in ExtJS library? Since i have seen the comments written in library file, stating that there is a problem with iframe.

Can anyone help me on how to solve this IE issue?

Comment: exactly same problem! could you solve it?